Mean for product of random submatrix and its regularized inverse
I consider the following random circulant matrix
$$
 H_w = F^* \mathrm{diag}(w_1, \dots w_p)F, \, w_i\overset{iid}{\sim}\Gamma(1,1),
$$
where $F$ is the matrix for discrete Fourier transform, $F^*$ its complex conjugate.
Let $h_{w}$ be its square principal submatrix of order $r$, $r < p$ which is also leading (that is $h_w$ is an upper-left block of $H_w$ of size r).
I want to approximate the following expectation
$$
\mathbb{E}_w[(h_w + \mu\Sigma)^{-1}h_w], \, \mu > 0,
$$
where $\Sigma$ is diagonal with strictly positive elements, $\mu$ is a small but fixed parameter (one can consider limit $\mu \rightarrow 0$). I want to get the first-order correction to the above mean in $\mu$. Of course, this question can be generalized to arbitrary random matrices, however, I believe that there is a higher chance to get a closed answer for the special structure above. I would be also happy even with any concentration of measure result on the above product.
Note: Naive application of Neumann series (assuming that $h_w$ will dominate $\mu\Sigma$) gives first order correction $\mu h_w^{-1}\Sigma$. Expectation of such term in $w$ seems divergent, as $\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{-1}e^{-x}\, dx = +\infty$. Surely, it is a problem of expansion but not of the expectation itself.
$h_w$ is invertible almost surely, it is quite easy to show using Courant-Fisher characterization of eigenvalues that smallest eigenvalue of $h_w$ is not smaller than $\min(w_1, \dots, w_p) \sim \mathrm{Exp}(p)$.
p.s. I have seen that there is a lot of literature on random matrices with iid components but I have never seen anything like this.

I understood that my question is in fact not posed correctly - the Taylor expansion at $\mu=0$ for linear term in $\mu$ has additional $\log \mu$ multiplier. Therefore, it is not correct to speak about first-order correction, because lowest correction is of order $\mu\log\mu$.
Demonstration is amenable for $p=1$ (for $p > 1$ a similar result should hold). Let $p=1$, then the expectation is equivalent to
\begin{align}
 &\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x}{x+\mu}e^{-x}\, dx = 
 \int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}dx - \mu\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{x+\mu}\,dx\\
 & = 1 -\mu e^{\mu}\int\limits_{\mu}^{+\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx = 
1-\mu e^{\mu}E_1(\mu) = 1-\mu e^{\mu}(-\gamma - \log\mu + o(1))\\
& = 1+\mu(\gamma + \log\mu) + o(\mu).
\end{align}
For the matrix case I believe that the expansion should have form
\begin{equation}
 E_{w}(h_w + \Sigma)^{-1}h_w = I + c_1(\Sigma)\mu + c_1'(\Sigma)\mu\log\mu + o(\mu),
\end{equation}
therefore the question is about determining $c_1(\Sigma)$, $c_2(\Sigma)$.
p.s. I leave it for fun here, if you find those I will be happy to give credit for those, or I can reset my answer and set it as yours.
